Python Static Class Infinitely Pointing at Itself
I've been trying to implement an Env class with "dynamic" static attributes that get set at runtime. My goal was to try to mimic the implementation of libraries like dotenv, while avoiding needing to pass around an instantiated Env object (or even constantly re-instantiating) it in different modules. Finally, I got these two lines to work, my goal of the last night:
Env.load()
print(Env.vars.foo) == bar
The Problem: I was only able to get this to work through a hacky method of setting Env.vars to an instance of Env(). This has resulted in infinite/recursive chaining of memory addresses. For example, this is now valid too: Env.vars.vars.vars. Here is a visualization of it during debug:

I thought I was being cute and thought I had finally found a solution that works. I suppose I could leave it as is, since the memory address is just the same repeating one. But this feels like something beyond a mere code smell, and just feels so very wrong. But I can't for the life of me figure out the "right" way of implementing what I want.
Here is my current implementation:

...
Is this monstrosity actually ok, even if hacky? Is there another way you'd go about doing this, while having Env.vars.forever still be valid code?

Were you trying to have that __getattr__ apply to the class itself? If so, you need a metaclass for that, not @classmethod. @classmethod only changes argument binding, which isn't enough.

Please do not post images of code, please do not post images of text. Please post the code as code into the question.

After writing the answer, I do not think I understand. Just vars = argparse.Namespace(**self._dict). while having Env.vars.forever do you want to handle nested keys or do you want Env.vars.vars.vars to work? I do not understand what is that you are "having" with this code?

@user2357112 __getattr__ is overridden for static Env. It is called when one tries to access forever like so: Env.vars.forever. Upon failure on retrieving, getatr gets called, where I access the dictionary myself and return the desired. As I've mentioned, I don't want to deal with an Env object. I am using the static version of __getattr__ purposefully. How would a metaclass help specifically?

@KamilCuk Env.vars.vars.vars is just a side effect of my implementation. It was not my intention for it to work. It just does, because I couldn't find a way to get Env.vars.forever while assigning the env variables as attributes to the static Env. Which is why I ended up instantiating an Env object, and "hiding" it as the static vars.

@KamilCuk Before, I had another implementation where vars was the dict. But I just didn't like calling by keys as a string (was something like: Env.vars['forever']). Which is why I ended up overriding __getattr__. I really wanted the access of environment variables to look like either Env.forever or Env.vars.forever

@The-Stanislav: Well, you've got an Env object anyway. You're not avoiding it, and you're not using a "static version" of __getattr__. If you want a __getattr__ that applies to the Env class itself instead of the Env.vars instance you made, you need to write that __getattr__ on a metaclass.

Incidentally, forever was a very awkward choice of example name. Env.vars.forever sounds like it's shorthand for Env.vars.vars.vars.vars.vars... - it sounds like you're specifically trying to make indefinite chains of .vars accesses work.

@user2357112 You're just plain wrong. That's exactly what the cls is used for, while self would be pointing at an instance. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/class-method-vs-static-method-python/#

@user2357112 On the second one, you're absolutely right. I can see now why that would be confusing...

@user2357112 But Env.vars.vars.vars.vars.vars would be psychotic. I didn't actually think anyone could believe that would be a desired goal.

@The-Stanislav: No, seriously, it doesn't work like that. If it did, Env.whatever would trigger your __getattr__. All @classmethod does is change argument binding. On the other hand, a __getattr__ defined on a metaclass actually would be triggered for unknown attribute accesses on the class.

@user2357112 @classmethod is just a decorator. Anyways, I've actually implemented it. And know what happens with it, and without.

@user2357112 Though, your last comment has actually pointed out something interesting. Something I did not notice when changing from Env.bar to Env.vars.bar

Please read Why should I not upload images? and [edit] your question to use code-formatted text accordingly,
